# Can I Stage data to memory SELECT, then choose to rollback, or commit in sqlite3? python 2.7

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not sure how to best phrase this question:

I would like to UPDATE, ADD, or DELETE information in an SQLite3 Table, but I don't want this data to be written to disk yet. I would still like to be able to 
SELECT the data, and get the updated information, but then I want to choose to either rollback or commit.

Is this possible? Will the SELECT get the data before the UPDATE or after? Or must I rollback or commit before the next statement?

Comment: Yes you can. Selecting data doesn't need to commit. Haven't you tried it yoursef?

Answer (score 1):

From your tags I'm assuming you are using Python.  It may be an issue with the particular database driver.  Try using a database driver that does not use the Python DB API such as `apsw`.  Also, take at look at this post:

[Transactions with Python sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856976/transactions-with-python-sqlite3)

Answer (score 1):

(Disclosure: I am the author of apsw).  SQLite (the database not the python wrapper) supports exactly what you want, and there are multiple ways to achieve it.

Multiple nested levels of transactions are supported.  You can use [savepoints](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html) with only the outermost one actually causing a disk commit.  The same connection will see the pending changes but other connections will not (termed [isolation](https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html)).  Note pysqlite doesn't know about savepoints and can get very confused or not interoperate with them correctly.  APSW works just fine and you can just nest regular [with statements](http://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/connection.html#apsw.Connection.__enter__).

Separately from that approach you can create [temporary tables](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#tempdb) and then copy across the data into persistent ones when happy with it.  You can also attach or use [memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) which are similar.

Finally if you want multiple connections to see the pending data you can store that pending data in a different database file and attach it in each of the connections, copying data across into the main database as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly need to commit multiple times throughout the code, and you are worried about the performance times of transactions, you could always build the database in memory `db=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` and then dump it's contents to disk when all the time-critical aspects of the program have been completed. I.e the end of the script.