# Python sqlite transactions

Tags: python, sqlite

How do I use sqlite transactions in python?

The following code raises the exception `OperationalError: cannot commit - no transaction is active`
 on the `cur.execute('COMMIT')` line:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test(p)')
cur.execute('BEGIN')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test(p) values (?)', (1,))
cur.execute('COMMIT')
```

I've played around with `isolation_level` but none of the values gets rid of the exception.

Comment: Answers to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856976/transactions-with-python-sqlite3

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on autocommit mode:

```
con.isolation_level = None
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions
- http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html

Comment: Tried all the other values forgot to try out `None` :(

Comment: Doesn't autocommit mode mean that each `execute` is wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: No. It means that each execute is wrapped in a transaction, **unless** there is a transaction pending. "*Autocommit mode is disabled by a BEGIN statement. Autocommit mode is re-enabled by a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.*" -- http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html