# UPDATE .. RETURNING on older versions of sqlite with python interface?

Tags: python, sqlite

Here is a statement in Python3 using the [`sqlite3` built-in library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

```
self.cursor.execute(
     'UPDATE my_table set val = val+1'
     ' WHERE id=?'
     ' RETURNING val', (self.id,))
```

My beliefe is that this increments val and then returns it, all within one "transaction" no matter what the isolation level is on the connection.

However, [RETURNING is only supported as of sqlite 3.35.0](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_35_0.html), released March 2021.

How do I support this functionality through the python interface with an older sqlite, especially since this class doesn't control the connection's isolation level?

I thought about something like:

```
self.cursor.executescript("""
   BEGIN
   UPDATE my_table set val = val+1
   WHERE id=?;
   SELECT val WHERE id=?;
   COMMIT
   """, (self.id, self.id))
```

Well, `executescript` doesn't take query parameters.

I could separate it into two statements like this:

```
self.cursor.execute(
        'UPDATE my_table set val = val+1 WHERE id=?', (self.id,))
self.cursor.execute(
        'SELECT val FROM my_table WHERE id=?', (self.id,))
```

However, there's no guarantee they'll be in the same transaction.

As I said, this class doesn't control the isolation level of the connection.  It gets a connection. It could create a new connection or cursor if that's possible from an existing connection.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856976/transactions-with-python-sqlite3) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448465) (suggested in comments), I *think* issuing a BEGIN will start a transaction regardless of the isolation level of the connection.  In that case, the solution is

```
self.cursor.execute('BEGIN')
try:
    self.cursor.execute(
        'UPDATE my_table set val = val+1 WHERE id=?', (self.id,))
    self.cursor.execute(
        'SELECT val FROM my_table WHERE id=?', (self.id,))
    new_val = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
    self.cursor.execute('COMMIT')
except sqlite3.Error as err:
    self.cursor.execute('ROLLBACK')
    raise err
```

NOTE: Although it's possible this solution relies on the connection being in autocommit mode, since sqlite does not allow starting a transaction within another transaction.